# where is the xcode preview simulator inheriting from?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcode13

I used to have all my preview simulator device as iphone12 and I was fine with it. Not sure when, it all changed to I don't know iPhoneSE or iTouch with the thick bar. I did not want to change it back to iPhone12 by using the code .previewdevice() cuz I literally have like dozens of previews waiting for me to change, so I checked what decide the choice of the device. It shows as the screenshot below "inherited". There must be a source where I can the change the setting right? At least somewhere in the setting or I understand this "inherited" the wrong way? Can someone help give some more information about this? Can't believe xCode made this so inflexible...[screenshot from my Xcode project,the mysterious inherited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDMwy.png)

Comment: Inherited here means taken from your target destination, so once you change Destination (either in menu Product > Destination, or in toolbar are) your current preview changes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the run destination, which is something like `iPhone SE`. Just change it to the desired device type and the inherited device for previews will change accordingly.

If you want a special device type, as you said, just click on the top bar of the preview device and open the `Inspect Selected Object` menu (at the bottom of the `Canvas`), select the desired `Preview` `Device`. It will add the code `.previewDevice("iPad (9th generation)")` in the code preview section.